# Read multiple url content (file_get_contents or curl_exec) cause x loop of my script

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl, file-get-contents

I'm running a script in Codeigniter, PHP 7 on an online server (domain website).. The text read from this URL several times:
http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=FTSEMIB.MI&f=d1ohgl1vs

changes are only in s= (stock symbol)

My problem is that if I read x URL, my script finish reading all URL(symbols)
but it restarts many times in an irregular x cycles loop. I didn't understand that behavior.

max_execution_time is 1500. No error is coming out, and many times I only get a blank page.

My script in codeigniter/controller:

```
 private function _get_current_yahoo_data($stock_symbol) {

    $url = 'http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv';
    // ---- Stock Symbol ----
    $url.= "?s=".$stock_symbol;
    $url.= "&f=d1ohgl1vs"; 

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);    

    return $content;
 }  


 public function update_current_stocks_data() {

    $output = '';

    $import_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $s1 = time();
    $data = $this->data;

    $stocks = $data['stocks'];

    foreach($stocks as $s) {

        $id_stock = $s->id;


        $stock_symbol = $s->symbol;

        $p1 = time();
        $raw_quote_data = $this->_get_current_yahoo_data($stock_symbol);
        $p2 = time();

        $output.= $id_stock.' ';
        $output.= ' __ Time: '.($p2 - $p1).' seconds<br>';;


    }


    $s2 = time();

    $output.= '<br>Execution Time: '.($s2 - $s1).' seconds';

    $this->stock_model->log($import_date, $output);

    $output.= '<br>';
    $output.= strlen($output);
    $data['output'] = $output;
    $this->load->view("simple_view", $data);

}
```

I'm looking in my log table (populated from function log) and there are several log rows launching the script only one time!

Every script is during about 100 seconds for a total of 259 stocks
if i reduce the stock list, for example 230 there are no problems and the script is running only one time. The funny thing is that if I do read every 259 stocks script loop several time.

Comment: you can run this loop on command line interface or using cron jobs. Because in browser mode script has max execution timeout exists. If you are running in linux redhat then you have to alter selinux settings

Comment: if I launch phpinfo() I see max_execution_time(local) = 1500

Comment: selinux settings is an super control than phpinfo details https://blog.lysender.com/2015/07/centos-7-selinux-php-apache-cannot-writeaccess-file-no-matter-what/